# ASP. NET MVC 5 Images routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have ASP.NET MVC application, something like Wiki. This app has a lot of pages and the pages use pictures. Pages contents are stored in database however their images are stored in file system. I decided to move images from file system to database. Redently I have moved the images to database (using filetables in sql server). All is ok but now I faced with the problem. Previously, when images was stored in folder, I used them so:

```
<img src='/Attachments/myImage.png' />
```

But now I get image's data from db:

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    public FileResult GetFile(string filename)
    {
        byte[] data = .... // here is retrieving data from db;
        string mimeType = ... // here is detecting mime type           
        return File(data, mimeType);
    }
}
```

and src attributes of img-tags are changed:

```
<img src='/Images/GetFile?filename=myImage.png' />
```

It is a problem for me because I have to edit all of my pages and change image links. Is there any way to redirect image's requests from `/Attachemts/myImage.png` to `Images/GetFile?filename=myImage.png`  without editing all pages contents? I tried to use the foolowing route:

```
routes.MapRoute("old images", "Attachments/{filename}",
new
{
    controller = "Images",
    action = "GetFile"
});
```

but I failed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure the Attachments folder is not excluded from routing. Search for and remove something like this: routes.IgnoreRoute("Attachments/{*pathInfo}")

Comment: @Tacud this folder is not excluded

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did a little research myself, since I'm going to need to solve something similar and I believe this is what you're looking for: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works

It turns out that MVC doesn't intercept any url with extension and you need to change the behavior.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is true, but the better approach is to do the redirect at the IIS-level. Having MVC handle *all* static files is going to slow down your application unnecessarily.